# How to get all the content submitted, using knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js to provide a survey form of sorts, and I'm wanting to pickup the feedback and post it via an ajax call to my laravel server. I believe I've got the ajax part right, the laravel part's all good, but this whole javascript thing is new to me. Steep learning curve.

I've bound my model elements in the HTML, I've got the ajax call setup, but it's the little bit inbetween, the javascript/knockout where I'm not winning.

How do I acquire all the survey answers on the click of the button?

**HTML**

```
....
<td>
   <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> Poor    
   <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="2" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> Unsatisfactory   
   <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="3" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> As expected
   <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="4" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> Satisfactory
   <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="5" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> Excellent
<textarea name="Q1comment" rows="1" cols="50">Comments</textarea>
</td>
<button data-bind="click: SurveyViewModel">Submit</button>
....
```

**The binding**

```
<script>
ko.applyBindings(new SurveyViewModel());
</script>
```

**javascript**

```
function SurveyViewModel() {
    this.Q1 = ko.observable(data.Q1);
    this.Q1comment = ko.observable(data.Q1Comment);
    alert(data.Q1);

    var thisOneEvaluation = {};
    thisOneEvaluation['answers'] = JSON.stringify(this.data);
    alert("The results are:" + JSON.stringify(this.data));
//        sendDataToServer(this.data);
}

function sendDataToServer(survey) {
//send Ajax request to your web server.
alert("Sending Data to Server...");
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/evaluations",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {
      'CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: ko.toJSON(self),
})

.done(function(data) {
    $('#status').html(data);
    if (result.url) {
        location.href = result.url;
    }
})

.fail(function(xhr) {
    $('#status').html("Failed");
});
```

}

Comment: where is your "radioSelectedOptionValue" observable declared in the model?

Comment: @Maxcot. Did my answer help?

Comment: Thanks Ray, I'm looking at it... educating myself :) ... I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

- It looks like you aren't actually capturing the checkbox or comment values. You need to define observables for both of them.
- You also seem to have a variable called `data` which I can't tell if you've already defined elsewhere in your code or you think is getting automatically defined.
- You cannot use `SurveyViewModel` for submitting the form. The sole purpose of `SurveyViewModel` is to act as a viewModel for the HTML.

Here are some corrections:

**HTML**

```
<td>
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> Poor    
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="2" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> Unsatisfactory   
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="3" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> As expected
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="4" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> Satisfactory
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="5" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue"> Excellent
<!-- Called a new observable called 'comment' -->
<textarea name="Q1comment" rows="1" cols="50" data-bind="value: comment">Comments</textarea>
</td>
<!-- Called a new function called 'submitData' -->
<button data-bind="click: submitData">Submit</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function SurveyViewModel() {
//You need to define this in your viewModel for the checkbox values to get registered. I am defining at as an observableArray because 'checked' binding can take multiple values.
this.radioSelectedOptionValue = ko.observableArray();
//To capture the comment:
this.comment = ko.observable();
//To get all data and send to server
this.submitData = function(){
    var jsonData = {
        'selectedOptions': this.radioSelectedOptionValue(),
        'comment': this.comment()
    }
    sendDatatoServer(jsonData);
};

this.Q1 = ko.observable(data.Q1);
this.Q1comment = ko.observable(data.Q1Comment);
alert(data.Q1);

var thisOneEvaluation = {};
thisOneEvaluation['answers'] = JSON.stringify(this.data);
alert("The results are:" + JSON.stringify(this.data));
//        sendDataToServer(this.data);
}

function sendDataToServer(survey) {
//send Ajax request to your web server.
alert("Sending Data to Server...");
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/evaluations",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {
      'CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    //it is already in JSON format
    data: survey,
})

.done(function(data) {
    $('#status').html(data);
    if (result.url) {
        location.href = result.url;
    }
})

.fail(function(xhr) {
    $('#status').html("Failed");
});
```